# Synchronized meteor with mysql

Tags: mysql, meteor

hello i'm developping a  angular2-meteor application and i'm using nodet-mysql

my problem i'm using the function Meteor.onConnect(the function) when i load my page n time the data will load n time from the database this is my code : 
      Loaduser.ts

```
   export function loaduser() {
   var Users:  Mysql.Collection<any> ;
        var connectionSettings = {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            port: 3300,
            password: '',
            database: 'my_db'
        };
    var db: Mysql.MeteorDatabase = Mysql.connect(connectionSettings);
    Users = db.meteorCollection<Object>("users", "usersCollection");
}
```

and there is the code of my main.ts

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

Meteor.onConnection(loaduser);
}
```

Comment: You could try `Meteor.startup(...)` instead. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_startup

Comment: thanks but Meteor.startup  works only in the beginning of the server loading , in my case i need it to works in repetetive mode (something like a moderate refresh)

Comment: Then modify the loaduser() function to keep the "db" variable in a permanent context (like the global context or a closure), and check whether it's reusable.

Comment: thanks but now i have another error :

Exception in onConnection callback: TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Comment: I believe that's a different issue.

Comment: what kind of issue you  think is it , and what i should focus on , because it seems that it works on the beginning and generates the error on the "aaply(db)" action